# Specifify ordered cateogry in pandas read_csv()

Tags: python, pandas

When reading a CSV file with pandas I can specify the column types via the `dtypes` parameter.

I can specify `category` like this.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import io
import csv
import pandas as pd

# there is a missing/empty value in 4th row
csv_data = """FOO;BAR\n
1;20204\n
5;20183\n
5;20182\n
4;20212\n"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data),
                 keep_default_na=False,
                 header=0,
                 sep=';',
                 dtype={'BAR': 'category'})

print(df.BAR)

print(df.BAR.cat.as_ordered())
```

`BAR` is a category but not `ordered`.
In my case it is easy to determine the ordering automatic. The values can be treated as strings or numbers.

Can I do something like `dtype={'BAR': 'ordered category'}`?

**EDIT**:
Because of the answers and comments that are out of my questions scope I would like to emphasise that I want to define the colum as an *ordered categorial* **while** `read_csv()`.
I know how to create a ordered categorial but not while reading a CSV file.

Comment: If you keep `BAR` as `int`, there is no need for a `Categorical` type. Ordered categories are useful when there is no natural way to sort the items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific answer to my specific question is, that it is not possible.

While doing `read_csv()` there is no way to specific an ordered category.

Comment: I stumbled upon this old question, yes [you can do that if you know the categories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77342680/16343464). If you don't know them, then it doesn't really make sense to use an ordered Categorical.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`pandas.Categorical`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Categorical.html). It has and `ordered` parameter.

```
>>> s = pd.Categorical(['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C'], categories=['B', 'A', 'C'], ordered=True)
>>> s
['A', 'B', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'C']
Categories (3, object): ['B' < 'A' < 'C']
>>> s.sort_values()
['B', 'B', 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C']
Categories (3, object): ['B' < 'A' < 'C']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `sort_values()` like this:

```
csv_data = """FOO;BAR\n
1;20204\n
5;20003\n
5;20182\n
4;20212\n"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data),
                 keep_default_na=False,
                 header=0,
                 sep=';',
                 dtype={'BAR': 'category'})

print(df.BAR)

print(df.BAR.sort_values(ascending=True))
```

which returns

```
0    20204
1    20003
2    20182
3    20212
Name: BAR, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['20003', '20182', '20204', '20212']
1    20003
2    20182
0    20204
3    20212
Name: BAR, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['20003', '20182', '20204', '20212']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can specify a custom [`CategoricalDtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.CategoricalDtype.html),  but this means that you must know the specific categories in advance.

```
MyCat = pd.CategoricalDtype(['20182', '20183', '20204', '20212'], ordered=True)

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(csv_data),
                 keep_default_na=False,
                 header=0,
                 sep=';',
                 dtype={'BAR': MyCat})
```

`df['BAR']`

```
0    20204
1    20183
2    20182
3    20212
Name: BAR, dtype: category
Categories (4, object): ['20182' < '20183' < '20204' < '20212']
```

In your example this doesn't really make sense as you already have lexicographically orderable value. Thus specifying the values there is not practical. Considering however another example such as `pd.CategoricalDtype(['Small', 'Medium', 'Large'], ordered=True)`, it's easy to see that the order must be specified in the beginning.